# what means "git fully backup"?

Tags: git, backup

One benefit of git is "every one can has full backup" as DVCS with respect to SVN.
I don't understand well.

Eg, John has a git repo with his branch branch_a, Peter has another git repo with branch_b.
The branch_a  and branch_b are different, without sync backup is not complete.
As SVN they also can pull all code to local, is it also a kind of "full backup"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every clone of a repository is a full .. well, clone of the repository: It contains every commit. When you say

> As in SVN [..] is it also a kind of "fully backup"

it is wrong, because in SVN you only checkout a specific revision into the local workspace, that's all. Especially: When you network connection is down, you cannot do anything with SVN. Because a git repository has every commit (as long as you'll fetch all of them from time to time, for example via `git fetch --all`) you can work as usual and push to the remote one later. Even more if someone breaks the remote repository *every* developer has a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

In "normal" usage of SVN, you only have a single branch checked out, and only the most recent version of that. If you want another branch, or an older version of a file, you need to go to the server. You could check out the whole repository, but again, only the current version. For more, you'd need to set up repository replication, which is complicated and definitely not part of the normal developer workflow.

In git, you can easily get a *complete* copy of all data from the server, by just the normal checkout procedures. You usually start with a "clone", which has everything. Even if you only "pull" a single branch, you still get the complete history of everything in there.